# Creating a cell that updates to new value

Tags: excel

I am wondering if there is any way to create a cell that automatically updates to the next in a series in Excel.

If Column 2 contains any of these:

```
2A
2B
2C
```

Then the cell would say use 2D next. And then when that column shows 2D, then use 2E, and so on.  I have tried using an if function, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I plan on having the list of available entries on a separate worksheet that the data will draw from.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What happens after `2Z`?

Comment: So ideally it would run continuously and move on to the next number after 2Z, so then 3A  and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

Have the text "2A" in cell `A1`.

In cell `A2`, paste this formula:

```
= LEFT(A$1,LEN(A$1)-1)&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(A$1,1))+ROWS(A$1:A2)-1)
```

And drag down as necessary.

---

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you can modify cell `A2` to this:

```
= IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="Z",(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)+1)&"A",
  LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))+1)
```

Comment: That does work!  Now I just need to figure out to get it to go to 3A, and not 2{ (which is what it just did).  But this has helped tremendously!

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you very much!